# Bukkit plugin kick reason only using first word

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I'm making a kick/ban command for my server and the format is /kick name reason.
I got it all working but the `reason` can only be 1 word and anything over that excludes it, for example `/kick BattleDash hello world` would say BattleDash was kicked for `hello`.

Here's my code:

```
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kick") && sender instanceof Player) {

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        int length = args.length;

        if (length >= 2) {

            boolean playerFound = false;

            for (Player playerToKick : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
                if(playerToKick.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])) {
                    playerToKick.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "Kicked by Administrator " + player.getName() + "\nReason: " + args[1]);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[BATTLEDASHLOGS]: Kicked player " + playerToKick.getName() + "succesfully!");
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (playerFound == false) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[BATTLEDASHLOGS]: " + args[0] + " was not found!");
            }

        } else player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[BATTLEDASHLOGS]: Incorrect arguments!" + ChatColor.RED + " /kick <PlayerName> <reason>");

    return true;

}
```

(Also if you don't include a reason it gives internal error in chat and exception occured in console)

Comment: Update: I got kicks without reasons working but reasons still only show the first word
`      if (length >= 2) {
       playerToKick.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "Kicked by Administrator " + player.getName() + "\nReason: " + args[1].toString());
      }
      else if (length >= 1) {
       playerToKick.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "Kicked by Administrator " + player.getName() + "\nReason: " + "Not Specified");
      }```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is doing that due to the way it was programmed.

If we take a look at line that takes the argument:

```
playerToKick.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "Kicked by Administrator " + player.getName() + "\nReason: " + args[1]);
```

We can see that you're only using `args[1]`. If we see a message as an array, the problem will be clear:

At position 0 (remember arrays start at 0): BattleDash

1: hello

2: world

When you take only `args[1]` to your message, only `hello` would be used! What we need to do instead, is use all the arguments. One way to do that is like this:

```
// First, transform your array into a list, so it's easier to understand
List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<>(args);

String playerName = arguments.get(0);  // Get the player name
arguments.remove(0);   // Remove the player name from our arguments list, we don't want it in the message

String message = String.join(" ", arguments);  // Combine all the other arguments into a message
```